# C# Get All file names without extension from directory

Tags: c#

Im looking for a way to read ALL txt files in a directory path without their extensions into an array. Ive looked through the path.getFileNameWithoutExtension but that only returns one file. I want all the *.txt file names from a path i specify

THanks

Answer (score 17):

```
Directory.GetFiles(myPath, "*.txt")
    .Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension)
    .Select(p => p.Substring(1)) //per comment
```

Comment: One more requirement is that i need to trim the First character off all file names. HOw do i do this?

Comment: a single select is more efficient than two ^^

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear.  
`filename.Substring(0,1)` will give you ONLY the first char.
`filename.Substring(1)` will give you everything BUT the first char.

Answer (score 5):

Something like:

```
String[] fileNamesWithoutExtention = 
Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\", "*.txt")
.Select(fileName => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName))
.ToArray();
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
var files = from f in Directory.EnumerateFiles(myPath, "*.txt")
            select Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f).Substring(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

just need to convert it to Array[]

```
   string targetDirectory = @"C:\...";

// Process the list of files found in the directory. 
   string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory,  "*.csv").Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension).Select(p => p.Substring(0)).ToArray();

   foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
        {
          //Code
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var filenames = Directory.GetFiles(myPath, "*.txt")
.Select(filename => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename).Substring(1));
```

(the substring(1)) added for a specification in commentary)

Answer (score -1):

```
public void getTestReportDocument(string reportid, string extenstype)
{
    try
    {
        string filesName = "";
        if (sqlConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlConn.Open();
        if(extenstype == ".pdf")
        {
            filesName = Path.GetTempFileName();
        }
        else
        {
            filesName = Path.GetTempFileName() + extenstype;
        }

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetTestReportDocuments", sqlConn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportID", reportid);

        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.Default))
        {
             while (dr.Read())
             {
                 int size = 1024 * 1024;
                 byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                 int readBytes = 0;
                 int index = 0;
                 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filesName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                 {
                     while ((readBytes = (int)dr.GetBytes(0, index, buffer, 0, size)) > 0)
                     {
                         fs.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                         index += readBytes;
                     }
                 }
             }
        }
        Process prc = new Process();
        prc.StartInfo.FileName = filesName;
        prc.Start();
   }

   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       throw ex;
   }
   finally
   {
       //daDiagnosis.Dispose();
       //daDiagnosis = null;
   }
}
```

finally i  got solution... i hope it will work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl0B1.png)